# Show that if $e^z$ is real, then $\Im(z)=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $e^z$ is real, then $\Im(z)=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

I got that the imaginary part is either $\pi +2\pi n$ or $2\pi n$ hence these are only ways $e^z=r$ where $r\in  \mathbb{R}$, but the right answer is $n\pi$

Comment: $\pi+2\pi n=\pi(1+2n)=\pi m$ where $m$ is an integer, so you're done.

Comment: Right, so the imaginary part being positive or negative real depends on m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already got that, then you are done. You got $(2n+1) \pi$ and $2n \pi$.

Realize numbers that are either $(2n+1) \pi$ or $2n \pi$ are essentially $\dots, -2\pi, -\pi, 0, \pi, 2\pi, \dots$ or $n \pi$ where $n$ is any integer.

Answer (score 1):

$e^z=e^x(cosy+isiny)$ is real $\implies e^x.siny=0$$\implies siny=0$ which gives $y=nπ, n\in \mathbb Z$